# Building Gradle project exported from Unity3D project: gradlew not found

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, apk

I am completely new to the Android build process and Gradle.

I have successfully exported a Gradle project from Unity3D in command line and got the following files in my output folder:

```
build.gradle        gradle.properties   launcher        local.properties    settings.gradle     unityLibrary
```

Now the next step is to turn this Gradle project into the apk file, from command line.

I have installed Android Studio on my MacOS machine, completed the first-run setup, and looked at the documentation to build from command line here (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline ). However `./gradlew build.gradle` gives `zsh: no such file or directory: ./gradlew` (all files in the folder are listed above and gradlew is not present) and `which gradlew` gives `gradlew not found` error.

I am stuck at this point and don't know what to do to get `gradlew` command working.

The reason I want to build everything from command line is that I have to automate the whole process in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This installs the required gradle cli

> brew install gradle

The below creates gradlew file in your project.

> gradle wrapper